# Am I doing something wrong with the sequence of keypresses for JEdit shortcut to "format paragraph" (C+ef)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jedit

JEdit has a feature to allow you to format a paragraph of text and the keypress is reported in the UI to be:

**`C+ef`**

I have tried this in a number of different ways without success:

1. Holding down the Control key followed by the 'e' key, followed by the 'f' key
2. Holding down the Control key and trying to stike both the 'e' key and the 'f' key simultaneously (seems impossible - one key is always struck first and it has the same effect as #1.)
3. Holding down the Control key and striking and releasing the 'e' key and then striking and releasing the 'f' key.

Because I use this feature a lot, it's quite cumbersome and slow to constantly have to use the UI. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be Ctrl+e *then* f ... but accordingly to the user guide the paragraph should be selected first,
[see here](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/paragraphs.html).